# DbContext not saving changes it shows it has

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The goal is simple. I need to update the LastUpdated column in the Schedule table. I've tried several different methods to achieve that goal but with no success. I'm certain the code is pointing to the correct database and I'm also checking the correct [local] database for the changes. When a break point is set on SaveChanges(), the code halts at that point. I can see that "db" contains the updated Date/Time information for the correct record. Yet, it does not save it to the database.

Having gone through Stack Overflow, I've tried some suggestions like using Attach and setting the Entity State [to Modified]. Neither of those suggestions worked. HasChanges returns false, even though I can see the change is applied to the context variable.

Also, the class this method is in contains other methods that have no problem accessing the database and doing some inserts. The below code is just three different attempts to give you an idea on how I'm trying to do it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void UpdateLastUpdated(int scheduleId)
{
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        var schedule = from s in db.Schedule where s.Id == scheduleId select s;
        schedule.FirstOrDefault().LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        db.SaveChanges();

        var schedule2 = db.Schedule.Find(scheduleId);
        schedule2.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;;
        db.SaveChanges();

        var schedule3 = db.Schedule.Single(s => s.Id == scheduleId);
        schedule3.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not updating? Check the SQL profilder to see if SQL is submitted. What database? You are aware that VS internal databases may be triggering you not seeing updates? How do you check that no updates are in the database? Local database project? You look at another copy than the program uns (and the one running is overwritten on every start).

Comment: When I do a SELECT * FROM Schedules in SSMS (after I do a continue on the break point of course), I can see the value hasn't changed. There are only three records in the table at the moment so its fairly easy to see nothing updated.

Comment: WHich may not mean they have not changed - only you look at the wrong database, as I said. Profile, check whether SQL is submitted.

Comment: What type of application are you building?

Comment: TomTom, I'm pretty confident its not the database thing. Even if I didn't verify the data. I can set a break point before the data is updated and the old value is there. Then, step into db.SaveChanges() and the data is in the context. I hit Continue and let the application complete, then run it again. Same thing happens, it starts with the old value, from the database.

Dan, its a windows form application.

Comment: Is your database file included in your project?

Comment: Can we see the code that will call your UpdateLastUpdated method?

Comment: Chris: No, it's a SQL database. Connection is via TCP. Keep in mind it's doing a fair amount of DB (reading, inserting, updating, etc.) already. In fact, I have a data grid view that is updating that table. Dan: Are you thinking some sort of deadlocking issue? I'm not using any sort of tasking in this project thus far.

Comment: Yes.  That's all I can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, after a lot of trial and error... The issue was because the column was computed. I tried updating another column in the same table from that method and it worked fine. Then I did some research on computed columns and found that to be the problem. After removing the annotation, the code works fine. Now I just need to figure out how to get the default value set without the annotation.

Thank you to everyone who offered solutions and comments. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You must indicate the change

```
db.Entry(schedule3).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

or

```
db.Entry(schedule3).Property(x => x.LastUpdated).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: You don't 'have' to indicate the entity state has been modified if change tracking is enabled on the context.

Comment: ok, thanks for the aclaration. I read more at respect in this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/working-with-change-tracking-proxy-in-entity-framework-6-0/

Comment: I've tried both of those and I'm still not getting an update. Going to read through these comment links. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't have to but this fixed a similar problem I had. Worth a try.